# Doxygen group module from file

Tags: c, grouping, doxygen

Is it possible to use Doxygen grouping so that all contents of a given file are grouped together, probably in what Doxygen calls a ["module"](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html#modules)? I am including a C library and in the documentation I want to separate out everything from the library without having to go through and manually document every item in the library as a group member.

Answer (score 1):

I found that when using `///` style documentation, adding

```
/// \addtogroup
/// \{
```

at the start of the file, and adding

```
/// \}
```

at the end of the file works for my purposes.